# Escape Sequence Single Quotes Error

Tags: apex, dynamic-soql, dynamic-apex

I am creating a dynamic query.

```
string s = '%' + searchText + '%';
string query = 'Select name, ShippingCity, ShippingState, ShippingCountry, rating, type, Industry, ownerId From Account Where name LIKE : '+s+' OR BillingAddress LIKE : '+s+' OR website LIKE : '+s+' OR AccountNumber LIKE : '+s;
```

> System.QueryException: line 1:122 no viable alternative at character '%'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap it in single quotes, not precede it with a colon (`:`).

```
String s = '\'%' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(searchText)  + '%\'';
... 'LIKE ' + s + '...';
```

Or if you want to use bind variables, you can just wrap your `searchText` variable:

```
searchText = '%' + searchText + '%';
... 'LIKE :searchText ...';
```